# ASP.NET Change how MVC REST API is called

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, rest

I am trying to figure out how to change the way my REST API is accessed. It's MVC architecture and currently one of my controllers looks like:

```
 [JsonpFilter]
 public class ItemController : Controller
 {
     public JsonResult GetItem(string id)
     {
         Item x = new Item(id);
         return Json(x, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
     }
 }
```

The reason you see the Jsonp filter is because I am accessing this API from a different domain through ajax and ajax doesn't support cross domain json requests.

So, right now you would access an Item like so because of the default routing:

```
api/Item/GetItem/4
```

However, I want to be able to do the following:

```
api/Item/4
```

and in the future be able to do something like

```
api/Item/4/Name
```

to get back just the name of the item with id 4.

How would I go about doing this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd really recommend Attribute Routing for MVC and Web API for specifying route information - http://attributerouting.net/

It is also built into the new version of MVC & Web API.

Its pretty simple to setup. You can just decorate your controller methods with an attribute like below in your case

```
[JsonpFilter]
[GET("api/Item/{id}")]
public JsonResult GetItem(string id)
{
  Item x = new Item(id);
  return Json(x, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```